# 90's TV show where a team of scientists bring their recently deceased friend back to life

Tags: story-identification

10-15 years ago, I watched an episode from a certain scifi show on cable TV. It had many similarities to Fringe or Torchwood, in that it starred a group of 3-4 people performing very unorthodox science within the confines of a workshop of sorts. However, the science was made to look realistic - no alien or supernatural elements involved as far as I could tell.

The episode started with someone close to the main team being shot or otherwise dying suddenly. The rest of the team brings his body to the workshop, and while they pronounce him dead, a member of the team suggests that they can resurrect him as long as they are quick. So they cool him down and administer him a series of injections in an attempt to keep his body from deteriorating. That's as far as I can remember. Oh, and they did revive him in the end.

Comment: Could it be one of the [Universal Soldier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Soldier_(series)) movies? (Cooling to heal someone made me think of it). Otherwise the timescale is right for an episode of The Outer Limits, but I don't see one on Wikipedia that fits.

Comment: From what I read of Universal Soldier, I don't think it matches the tone of this show as I remember it. The Outer Limits sounds fantastic, though, and maybe a fit.

Comment: What country? Also, anything else to indicate this is sci-fi rather than just an out-there action-adventure series?

Comment: Flatliners maybe?

Comment: That was my thought too. Flatliners movie.

Comment: They weren't trying to resurrect anyone in Flatliners; they were exploring the afterlife and defibulating themselves before being truely expired.

Comment: @Jsepia - Was 'Flatliners' the right answer, then?

Answer (score 6):

Per the comments above, I'm pretty sure you're referring to the film "[Flatliners](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099582/)".

### Starred a group of 3-4 people conducting unorthodox science in a workshop

Check - This film had an ensemble cast of five, typically with one of their number being chosen as the guinea pig. They were working in what appears to be a disused warehouse.

[image: Flatliners]

### From the 1990s

Check - Flatliners was produced in 1990 which means that it would have been shown on cable-TV sometime in the early- to mid-90's

### Film starts with someone being revived.

Check - The main characters attempt to revive a dying woman at the very start of the film.
Shortly afterwards, one of the main characters volunteers to be "flatlined" and then revived.

### Injections and cooling.

Check - the team use a mixture of refrigerated blankets and cool saline to prevent tissue necrosis.

Answer (score 4):

Since you specifically mentioned that it was a TV episode not a movie, then I think you're looking for the [Outer Limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Outer_Limits_(1995_TV_series)) (1995 version) episode "New Lease".

It fits the time frame, starts with scientists performing secret experiments to heal the cryogenically frozen and bring them back to life.  The process works to a degree, but those revived only last for a few days before they die again.

> After Houghton is shot dead by a mugger in the parking lot, McCamber re-animates him.

The process usually involved freezing the body, then using a complicated machine involving lasers to rebuild the damaged parts of the body... however, an injection in the neck is also a major part of the process (possibly to drain the blood and then put it back in).

He does in fact get revived, but believes that he's only got a short time to live.  He's torn between spending some final time with his family and seeking revenge on the man who killed him.  He does some of both, but pursues the latter.

But it turns out

> specifics about the way he was revived or the time it took to get to him means that he'll survive after all.  Except, he just murdered the person who killed him, and will now be going to jail for it.  Oops.

The major difference between this possibility and your recollection is that the scientist doesn't die until about halfway through the episode.  However, the episode does begin with somebody else being revived and them trying to keep him from dying painfully like all the previous test subjects.  It's close enough that it could easily be conflated in memory.

Comment: Wow, that sounds very very close to what I can remember from it. Especially the shooting and the part about draining the blood. I'll have to get my hands on that episode but it definitely sounds like it.

Comment: I watched the episode. I'd never seen that piece of TV in my life, and the characters I remembered were not there (specifically the 3-4 people). I'm starting to question my own sanity at this point. Nice match though.

Comment: Well I can't vouch for your sanity, but cooling the body down to prevent damage while trying to heal it was a cool and a lot of SFish shows played with it so it still could easily have been something else.  I have a vague memory of something similar possibly being done on Tales from the Crypt once. I'll keep an eye out for other possibilities.

Comment: One thing... do you think it was a single episode of an ongoing series with the same characters, or an anthology series, or do you simply not know?

Comment: I have no idea if the characters were one-offs (such as in Outer Limits) or recurring ones. But I'm pretty sure this was an episode of a TV series. The plot as I remember it was too simple for a movie.